# Replicating dismissViewController animation

Tags: ios, animation

I have a view controller that I am trying to pop. The animation that I would like to use is the same as the animation that would show when `dismissViewController` would be called. What would be the best way to replicate this for `popToRootViewController`. I know how to create custom view controller animations, but I was wondering what will be the best way to do this?

Comment: If you know how to create custom view controller animations, what's the question?

Answer (score 0):

To control the animation that happens when you call popToRootViewControler, you'll just need to set your navigation controller's delegate and implement the UINavigationControllerDelegate method:

```
- (id<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController animationControllerForOperation:(UINavigationControllerOperation)operation fromViewController:(UIViewController *)fromVC toViewController:(UIViewController *)toVC
```

From there, you'll return `self` or any object where you can implement the `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` method:

```
- (void)animateTransition:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext
```